# KENDOUI: Grid Popup Edit with datePicker Plugin not updating its time value

Tags: datepicker, refresh, kendo-grid

I've got a Kendo ui grid within my web application. I can directly create a new dataset with popup editing. A given field is usable as datePicker.

My Problem is, if I logon to my webapplication @ 8 a.m. and click on the create data button in the afternoon the field is populated with 8 a.m.

how can I force the datePicker to refresh, if I call the create function from the toolbar of my grid?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I found the solution. May it will help someone else out. You can use the edit function from the grid itself, to set the value of a given column:

```
edit: function(e){
    if (e.model.isNew()) {
         e.model.set("jtrDate", new Date());
    }
}
```

As in my example, my column Name is jtrDate.

[Grid Edit Function](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/web/grid#events-edit)